# Compare Previous Row value with Current Row Value Without Using Loops in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, performance, compare

**Source Table**

| Row_no | Flag | Curr_value | Prev_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C | V1 | NULL |
| 2 | P | V11 | NULL |
| 3 | P | V12 | NULL |
| 4 | C | V2 | NULL |
| 5 | C | V31 | NULL |
| 6 | P | V32 | NULL |

I have a scenario where i have to compare previous row value with current row value and update the Curr_value column based on a case condition  and the curr_value  and Prev_value should be derived for all the records in the table.

The condition used to derive Curr_value column is case when (Flag='C') then curr_value else Prev_value end  and I’m using LAG function in MSSQL to get Previous value column.

**OUTPUT**

| Row_no | Flag | Curr_value | Prev_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C | V1 | 0 |
| 2 | P | V1 | V1 |
| 3 | P | V1 | V1 |
| 4 | C | V2 | V1 |
| 5 | C | V3 | V2 |
| 6 | P | V3 | V3 |

I tried implementing the same using While Loop but the execution time is very high. Please let me know if the same output can be achieved without using loops in MSSQL.

Comment: Have you looked into SQL Server's [LAG (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql) and [LEAD (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) functions yet?

Comment: yes i'm using lag function to get the Previous value

Comment: The `OUTPUT` is your required result or your current query result ?

Comment: The given output is my required result

Answer (score 0):

I set up the following script as a complete working example:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpSampleData(
    Row_no int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY  
    ,Flag varchar(1) NULL
    ,Curr_value varchar(3) NULL 
); 

INSERT INTO #tmpSampleData (Row_no,Flag,Curr_value) 
VALUES (1, 'C', 'V1')
,(2, 'P', 'V1')
,(3, 'P', 'V1')
,(4, 'C', 'V2')
,(5, 'C', 'V3')
,(6, 'P', 'V3'); 

SELECT 
    sample_data.Row_no
    ,sample_data.Flag
    ,sample_data.Curr_value
    ,LAG(sample_data.Curr_value,1,'0') OVER(ORDER BY sample_data.Row_no) AS Prev_value
    ,CASE 
        WHEN sample_data.Flag = 'C'
            THEN sample_data.Curr_value
        ELSE LAG(sample_data.Curr_value,1,'0') OVER(ORDER BY sample_data.Row_no)
    END AS CalculatedField
FROM 
    #tmpSampleData AS sample_data; 

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tmpSampleData', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN 
    DROP TABLE #tmpSampleData; 
END;
```

But I think the main part you are interested in here is just this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN sample_data.Flag = 'C'
        THEN sample_data.Curr_value
    ELSE LAG(sample_data.Curr_value,1,'0') OVER(ORDER BY sample_data.Row_no)
END AS CalculatedField
```

Simply add your condition of `sample_data.Flag = 'C'` and then either return `Curr_value` or the result of your `LAG

Answer (score 0):

Just use Lag function...

```
Create table #temp
(
id int,
Fuel int,
dates date
)

Insert into #temp values(1,10,getdate())
Insert into #temp values(2,5,getdate()+1)
Insert into #temp values(3,18,getdate()+2)
Insert into #temp values(4,10,getdate()+3)
Insert into #temp values(5,8,getdate()+4)
Insert into #temp values(6,20,getdate()+5)
Insert into #temp values(7,10,getdate()+6)

Select * from (
SELECT id,
    LAG(Fuel, 1) OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS previous_Fuel , Fuel, dates
FROM #temp )A where Isnull(previous_Fuel,0) < Fuel
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).