Handling Overlapped Time Periods
I have 4 different time periods, a, b, c, and d.

a overlaps with b
b overlaps with c
a and c do not overlap
d does not overlap with a, b or c

However, I'd like to be able to chain these all into a single time period, no matter how many different time periods could possibly chain together. Another challenge is I have other time periods that don't overlap, so I can't simply MIN() and MAX() across all the data.
Below is my current attempt
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #test
CREATE TABLE 
    #test (id VARCHAR, start_time DATETIME2, end_time DATETIME2)
INSERT INTO
    #test
VALUES 
    ('a', '2024-08-03 12:35:37', '2024-08-07 12:36:42'),
    ('b', '2024-08-06 18:35:53', '2024-08-10 13:12:50'),
    ('c', '2024-08-09 12:40:13', '2024-08-11 00:00:00'),
    ('d', '2024-01-09 12:40:13', '2024-02-11 00:00:00');


WITH overlaps AS (
    SELECT
        a.id,
        a.start_time AS orig_start,
        a.end_time AS orig_end,
        LEAST(a.start_time, b.start_time) AS overlap_start,
        GREATEST(a.end_time, b.end_time) AS overlap_end
    FROM
        #test AS a
    LEFT JOIN
        #test AS b
            ON b.id != a.id -- Don't overlap with self
            AND GREATEST(a.start_time, b.start_time) < LEAST(a.end_time, b.end_time) -- catch any overlap time periods
),
merged AS (
    SELECT
        a.id,
        a.orig_start,
        a.orig_end,
        MIN(overlap_start) AS merged_start,
        MAX(overlap_end) AS merged_end
    FROM
        overlaps AS a
    GROUP BY
        a.id,
        a.orig_start,
        a.orig_end
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    id,
    merged_start,
    merged_end
FROM
    merged
ORDER BY
    merged_start;

Desired end goal would be a table like:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #desired
CREATE TABLE 
    #desired (rn INT, start_time DATETIME2, end_time DATETIME2)
INSERT INTO
    #desired
VALUES 
    (1, '2024-01-09 12:40:13', '2024-02-11 00:00:00'),
    (2, '2024-08-03 12:35:37', '2024-08-11 00:00:00');
SELECT
    *
FROM
    #desired;


This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117962/what-is-a-simple-and-efficient-way-to-find-rows-with-time-interval-overlaps-in-s

Would LAG() be of use?  Compare prior date to see if it overlaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68357192/compare-previous-row-value-with-current-row-value-without-using-loops-in-mssql

Here is one way, it's not all that different from your attempt, just the last step has to stop grouping by id:
WITH AllPossibleOverlaps AS 
(
  SELECT t1.id,
       s = MIN(t2.start_time), 
       e = MAX(t2.end_time) 
    FROM      #test AS t1 
   INNER JOIN #test AS t2
      ON t2.end_time >= t1.start_time
     AND t2.start_time <= t1.end_time
   GROUP BY t1.id
),
OverlapsById AS 
(
  SELECT start_time = MIN(x2.s), 
         end_time   = MAX(x2.e) 
    FROM      AllPossibleOverlaps AS x
   INNER JOIN AllPossibleOverlaps AS x2
      ON x.e >= x2.s 
     AND x.s <= x2.e
   GROUP BY x.id
)
SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY start_time), 
       start_time,
       end_time 
   FROM OverlapsById
  GROUP BY start_time, 
           end_time
  ORDER BY rn;


db<>fiddle

A slightly shorter way is to combine DISTINCT and GROUP BY, which feels icky to me:
WITH AllPossibleOverlaps AS 
(
  SELECT t1.id,
       s = MIN(t2.start_time), 
       e = MAX(t2.end_time) 
    FROM      #test AS t1 
   INNER JOIN #test AS t2
      ON t2.end_time >= t1.start_time
     AND t2.start_time <= t1.end_time
   GROUP BY t1.id
)
  SELECT DISTINCT 
         start_time = MIN(x2.s), 
         end_time   = MAX(x2.e) 
    FROM      AllPossibleOverlaps AS x
   INNER JOIN AllPossibleOverlaps AS x2
      ON x.e >= x2.s 
     AND x.s <= x2.e
   GROUP BY x.id;


db<>fiddle

